# Why do wildcards in GROUP BY statements not work?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

I am trying to make the following SQL statement work, but I get a syntax error:

```
SELECT A.*, COUNT(B.foo)
FROM TABLE1 A
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.PKey = B.FKey
GROUP BY A.*
```

Here, A is a wide table with 40 columns and I would like to avoid listing each column name in the GROUP BY clause if possible. I have many such tables over which I have to run a similar query, so I will have to write a Stored Procedure. What's the best way to approach this?

I am using MS SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`GROUP BY A.*` is not allowed in SQL.

You can bypass this by using a subquery where you group by, and then join:

```
SELECT A.*, COALESCE(B.cnt, 0) AS Count_B_Foo
FROM TABLE1 AS A
  LEFT JOIN 
      ( SELECT FKey, COUNT(foo) AS cnt
        FROM TABLE2 
        GROUP BY FKey
      ) AS B 
    ON A.PKey = B.FKey ;
```

---

There is a feature in SQL-2003 standard to allow in the `SELECT` list, columns that are not in the `GROUP BY` list, as long as they are functionally dependent on them. If that feature had been implemented in SQL-Server, your query could have been written as:

```
SELECT A.*, COUNT(B.foo)
FROM TABLE1 A
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.PKey = B.FKey
GROUP BY A.pk                          --- the Primary Key of table A
```

Unfortunately, this feature has not yet been implemented, not even in SQL-Server 2012 version - and not in any other DBMS as far as I know. Except for MySQL which has it but inadequately (inadequately as: the above query will work but the engine will do no checking for functional dependency and other ill-written queries will show wrong, semi-random results).

As [@Mark Byers](http://stackexchange.com/users/24377/mark-byers?tab=accounts) informed us in a comment, **[PostgreSQL 9.1 added a new feature](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.1#SQL_and_PL.2FPgSQL_features)** designed for this purpose. It is more restrictive than MySQL's implementation.

Comment: Can you mention a couple of RDBMS's that implement that portion of the standard as written? I know, for example, that MySQL will allow you (given the proper settings) to include items not within the `GROUP BY` clause in the `SELECT` list, but it leaves it undefined as to which row that value will come from (so if the column or expression *isn't* functionally dependent upon the grouping expression, then it *could* come from any row within the group).

Comment: @Adam: No, I know no RDBMS that has it implemented. MySQL has it but inadequately, as your comment says.

Comment: Gotcha. I was actually asking if there were, since I have experience with far fewer RDBMS's than I would imagine most of the people answering questions on this site would have ;) But that was my suspicion.

Comment: "and not in any other DBMS as far as I know." PostgreSQL 9.1 added a [new feature](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.1#SQL_and_PL.2FPgSQL_features) designed for this purpose. It is more restrictive than MySQL's implementation.

Comment: @MarkByers: thnx, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 25):

In addition to @ypercube's workaround, "typing" is never an excuse for using `SELECT *`. I've [written about this here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list), and even with the workaround I think your `SELECT` list should still include the column names - even if there are a massive number like 40.

Long story short, you can avoid typing these big lists by clicking and dragging the Columns node for the object in Object Explorer onto your query window. The screen shot shows a view but the same thing can be done for a table.

[image]

But if you want to read about all the reasons *why* you should subject yourself to this huge level of effort of dragging an item a few inches, [please read my post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list). :-)

Comment: In PostgreSQL (with EMS SQL Manager), I do this defining a view as `SELECT *` and then copy the field list from the view definition.

Comment: I certainly agree that `SELECT *` should not be used. I'm curious about the `GROUP BY` case though. @Aaron, are there efficiency issues with having 40 columns in the Group By list?

Comment: @ypercube there can be, sure. Your workaround is much better because it avoids them. I'm curious in what situation there will be a possibility that all 40 columns in a table have the same values on multiple rows. No key? What do these columns mean? What does grouping them mean? Seems very edge case to me.

Comment: @ypercube - As far as I've seen if you group by `A.PK, A.some, A.other, A.columns` it doesn't bother actually comparing  `some, other, columns` this is just required by the syntax.

Comment: @Aaron, neat trick with dragging the columns from object explorer.  Any idea why it also works for Keys, Constraints and Statistics but not for Indexes?

Comment: @datagod sorry, no, any gaps could only be explained by the SSMS dev team. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Well it depends on your use case. Sometimes you really **do** want to `select*`.

Comment: @Pacerier Sorry, [I disagree completely](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list), but maybe you could elaborate.

Comment: I like this way, it is real simple and requires just one drag of the mouse

Answer (score 0):

**This may be better addressed with an outer apply.** (thus eliminating the need for the group by *)

**If you are confident of an 1:n cardinality:**

```
SELECT A.*, B.CountFoo
FROM TABLE1 A
outer apply (select count(B.Foo) as CountFoo from TABLE2 B where A.PKey = B.FKey) B
```

**If Table1 has duplicates on PKey** (though depending on your use, you start to have a wash in terms of complexity vs just doing the group by):

```
;with DupRows as 
(
    SELECT A.*
        ,MultipledCountFoo = B.CountFoo * Count(*) over (partition by A.PKey)
        ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by A.PKey order by A.PKey)
    FROM TABLE1 A
    outer apply (select count(B.Foo) as CountFoo from TABLE2 B where A.PKey = B.FKey group by A.) B
)
Select * from DupRows where RN=1
```

**Avoiding "Select * "**

It is important to note there are cases with CTEs where the physical column selection is done previously/later and the "all columns" selection becomes useful/practical and does not affect the execution plan.  Yes, you need to EVENTUALLY limit your column selection and that needs to happen prior to any materialization (ie union all), but there are acceptable uses of select *.

**Version Support**

FYI, it looks like this is supported on sql server 2008 (r2?) but it's getting harder and harder to search for the documentation prior to 2016.  Also hard for me to say how outer apply performed on 2008.  I can confirm it is black-magic-awesome in the later versions compared to equivalent nested queries.