# group by and having query need help?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using the pub database in SQL Server 2005. Which stores have at least 5 orders? Should diplay the store name and store id. I have come up with a query something like this:

```
select 
    stores.stor_name
    , sales.stor_id  
from 
    sales 
join 
    stores 
on  sales.stor_id =stores.stor_id 
group by 
    sales.stor_id  
having 
    (count(sales.stor_id)>=5)
```

When answering please mention what i have done wrong

Comment: Use `group by sales.stor_id, stores.stor_name`

Comment: You have to group all columns treated in the projection or use aggregate functions

Comment: Exactly. Or use a subquery (where you group by) and then join, as in this answer: [Why do wildcards in GROUP BY statements not work?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21226/why-do-wildcards-in-group-by-statements-not-work/21228#21228)

Comment: @ypercube thanks ypercube for the fast reply and it did worked for me thanks again

Comment: @edze thanks for your opinion well edze can you please help me to provide some tips to master the sql with some tutorial in internet and also books to refer because i often make small mistakes like these even though i know all the keywords(not all though ) but dont have a proper idea to use them please help to make a concrete foundation on sql

Comment: @Bijujose: a fast search reveals a few links: [sql-language-tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322297/sql-language-tutorial)

Comment: @mark storey smith thanks mark for editing .Next time i will keep in my mind to write the questions far better

Comment: @ypercube well i think the post i made for getting the tutorials is against the rule of stack exchange what should i do ypercube may i delete the post?

Comment: @Biju: it's a comment, no worries. You can always flag a comment of yours if you want (explaining that you think it should be removed) and a moderator will remove it. Also, if you want to ask something and you are not sure if it allowed or a good fit for a question, you can join [the Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap) chat room. There's almost always someone there.

Comment: @Mark Storey-Smith thanks mark for the edit i have a little doubt ,how did you colored the elements in the query like the select ,from ,join all got a brown color how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

**ypercube** already gave the right answer, but here's another alternative:

Instead of GROUPing by all columns (leading to a bloated `GROUP BY this, that, that, and_that_too`), the following can be used:

```
select 
    sales.stor_id,  
    MIN(stores.stor_name) AS stor_name
from 
    sales 
join 
    stores 
on  sales.stor_id =stores.stor_id 
group by 
    sales.stor_id  
having 
    (count(sales.stor_id)>=5)
```

Though I confess we just move the bloating around... But this at least clarifies the mechanism of the query, by simplifying the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: when i used your query it just show an error like "incorrect syntax near stores" i think the MIN function you used is not the correct one to use please check your query

Comment: 'sales.stor_id,' you need the comma

Comment: now it worked shlomi noach thanks for extra info