# PostgreSQL requires "GROUP BY" when aliasing a table?

Tags: postgresql, alias

Here's something strange: there is a large table named "products" which is partitioned with inheritance such that there are two children: products_active and products_inactive, and the constraint is that in products_active, `status=1`, and products_inactive gets all the other statuses.

There is a large query which joins a bunch of tables, of which this is the first part:

```
SELECT
  products.id, products.status, products.brand_id, products.name, products.description, products.data, products.website,
  products.packaging, products.container, products.country_of_origin, products.category_id, products.product_type_id, products.tsv_keywords,
  COUNT(prices.id) as prices_count,
  ROUND(AVG(currency_convert(prices.amount,currencies.currency_code,'USD')),2) as avg_price,
  ROUND(MAX(currency_convert(prices.amount,currencies.currency_code,'USD')),2) as high_price,
  ROUND(MIN(currency_convert(prices.amount,currencies.currency_code,'USD')),2) as low_price,
  ts_rank(tsv_keywords, plainto_tsquery('merlot')) as rank,
  ROUND(AVG(ST_Distance(ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(0.001 0.001)'),ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(' || stores.longitude || ' ' || stores.latitude || ')')))) AS distance
FROM
  products
  JOIN product_types ON products.product_type_id = product_types.id
  JOIN categories ON products.category_id = categories.id
  JOIN prices ON prices.product_id = products.id 
  JOIN currencies ON prices.currency_id = currencies.id
  JOIN stores ON prices.store_id = stores.id
  JOIN brands ON products.brand_id = brands.id
  JOIN merchants ON stores.merchant_id = merchants.id
  JOIN manufacturers ON brands.manufacturer_id = manufacturers.id
, delivery_zones
WHERE ...
```

(full query here: http://pastebin.com/VjJPTQWj)

The problem is: note the `FROM products...` part, if I replace this with `FROM products_active AS products`, the query errors out with:

```
ERROR:  column "products.status" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2:   products.id, products.status, products.brand_id, products....
```

The two tables (products and products_active) have identical structures! They are inherited from one another!

Am I missing a subtlety in aliasing table names?

Comment: Is products.id a primary/unique key in one table but not in the other?  You say they have identical structures, but that doesn't mean they're the same..

Comment: It's a unique index in the child tables: for `products` it's: `"products_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)` , and for products_active: `"index_products_on_active_id" UNIQUE, btree (id)`

Comment: I'll let someone else with more detailed knowledge answer, but I'll just say that normally you have to `GROUP BY` on ANY column that's not used in an aggregate.  You should have status, brand_id, name, description, etc ALL in your `GROUP BY` clause.  PostgreSQL is just doing something special to let you get away with only having the id column there.  (I'm guessing it's because it's the `PRIMARY KEY` .. but again, someone else can answer authoritatively)

Comment: You are actually right! When I replaced the UNIQUE INDEX with PRIMARY KEY, the query worked again!

I'll leave this question for someone who knows what's going on to comment, I'm really interested in what is causing this.

Comment: Another thing I will point out is that a `UNIQUE INDEX` is not the same as a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`, which I'm sure is also factoring into the behavior.  (`CONSTRAINT`s are probably treated differently than `INDEXE`s) They certainly behave very similarly, but ... Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542794/postgres-unique-constraint-vs-index

Comment: @JoishiBodio: Actually, allowing non-GROUP BY columns to be referenced in SELECT without aggregation in cases like this is per SQL standard, as mentioned e.g. in [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21226/why-do-wildcards-in-group-by-statements-not-work/21228#21228).

Comment: @AndriyM - that sounds like you should post an answer, then.  ;)  Explain the SQL standard bit - I'm sure the OP would love to accept an answer for this question.  :)

Comment: @JoishiBodio: Nah, thanks. I'm merely aware of that relatively recent bit of the standard, as well as aware that PostgreSQL has implemented it. I wouldn't be able to explain e.g. why PG allows you to do that with a PK column but not with a UNIQUE column (if that is indeed the case). Would be nice if someone like Erwin Brandstetter or Craig Ringer chimed in – that would be authoritative all right, although pretty much anyone with experience in PG would be better than me. I'm just a T-SQL dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the 2 tables are not identical.

The first has `(id)` as the `PRIMARY KEY` while the second has `(id)` a `UNIQUE` constraint (or index, doesn't matter). This might seem like a minor detail but it isn't.

Postgres has added in [version 9.1, a feature](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.1#SQL_and_PL.2FPgSQL_features) were functionally dependent columns need not be mentioned in a `GROUP BY` clause (if the column they depend on is mentioned in the `GROUP BY`) and still used in the `HAVING`, `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` clauses. However the implementation is not 100% complete. It doesn't identify all possible functional dependencies but only those coming from `PRIMARY KEY` constraints. While a `UNIQUE` constraint with all columns `NOT NULL` does not differ in any meaningful way from a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, the implementation does not consider `UNIQUE` constraints.

So, for example, with these two very similar tables (test in [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/51a2c/3)):

```
CREATE TABLE products
  ( id INT NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    status TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
  ) ;

CREATE TABLE products_active
  ( id INT NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    status TEXT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (id)
  ) ;
```

The query will succeed for the first table:

```
SELECT p.id, p.status, p.name
FROM products AS p
GROUP BY p.id ;
```

while it will fail for the second:

```
SELECT p.id, p.status, p.name
FROM products_active AS p
GROUP BY p.id ;
```

with:

> ERROR: column "p.status" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

As one of the commenters said: the original query *should* have had a "GROUP BY" and PostgreSQL will accept a query without it in certain circumstances (see [Why do wildcards in GROUP BY statements not work?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21226/why-do-wildcards-in-group-by-statements-not-work/21228#21228)). This, combined with the information that UNIQUE indexes are *not the same* as PRIMARY KEYs (PK's disallow NULLs), solved this question.